# DNS lookup of external address in Quarkus application returns loopback address

Tags: java, dns, quarkus, inetaddress

I want to loopup the ip addresses of a headless kubernetes service to access each pod.
When testing it on the very pod with `getent hosts my-headless-service` it returns the 2 expected ips.
When I call `InetAddress.getAllByName("my-headless-service")` in my Quarkus application that runs on the same pod, I get the loopback address`[localhost/127.0.0.1]`

Are there any pit falls which I am not aware of when resolving a host name with Java?

Comment: What is meant by 'My java app is running native'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After wasting some time I discovered that quarkus has disabled name resolving by default due to security reasons.
Setting `quarkus.naming.enable-jndi=true` resolves the problem and the lookup works as expected using `InetAddress`.

See -> Disabling JNDI by default https://groups.google.com/g/quarkus-dev/c/bp1wVF1yLXE